# Get everything after domain names with apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to get everything include special character in apache webserver, php, htaccess (only)

When user key in

www.domain.com/whatever+here+must+get+back+include+special+character

The special character such as + ? \ # &

Now i have this htaccess code which only work pretty well but not for the special character i mention above

```
#route everything to index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?everything=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in my index.php, i have

```
echo $_GET['everything'];
```

I want it to really GET everything include the special character such as + ? \ # &

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP. No rewrite necessary. Although you'll never get what's after a hash. The browser _doesn't send it_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use `echo $_GET['everything'];`, use this instead:

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_array = explode('?',$url);
array_shift($url_array);
$everything = implode('?', $url_array);
echo $everything;
```

look: **[DEMO](http://codepad.org/xdYnx8Gx)**

**EDIT :**
I think its not possible to get anything after hash(#) using server-side script (PHP) since it's not sent to server. You have to use javascript;

Comment: -__-" sorry, I am in a middle of something. Thanks, many thanks.

Comment: No problem, just trying to help out

Comment: totally agreed with anything after # cant get it through htaccess and php

Comment: i manage to get what i want by just print_r($_SERVER), have a look on all server variable, i got what i want. And with the help of htaccess , i redirect everything to one file (like router).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the [NE](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) flag. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?everything=$1 [L,QSA,NE]
```